# FOSJsRoutingBundle & Karma: The route does not exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, symfony-3.4

I started writing tests for my huge AngularJS application. I used Router.generate() everywhere in my application.

First time I got this `Router is not defined`

So, I added a `router.js` to my `karma.conf.js`

```
files: [
  './web/vendor/angular/angular.js',
  './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  './web/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js',
  './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  './web/assets/js/**/*.js', // all project files
  './web/assets/js/app.js', // app where angular.module defined
  './web/assets/tests/**/*.js' // is where all tests placed
],
```

And now I end up with `'The route "api_get_users" does not exist'`, as I understand `api_get_users` is a first `Router.generate` call encountered by Karma while loading files.

As I may understand the error is going from routing bundle, not from Karma, so it unable to find list of available routes and I'm not really understand how can I pre-load those routes.

Please, help me to find a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I found an answer so far, hope this would be helpful

just generate a routes as shown in [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/commands.html) and then include `fos_js_routes.js` file into Karma `files` section